# ¿De qué manera puedo lograr que aparezca marcado por defecto un ítem?

Tags: javascript, css

Estoy creando mi portfolio de Desarrollador Web luego de haber estado meses estudiando HTML y CSS e incursionando actualmente en JavaScript.

En mi sección de Hardskills decidí agregar un poco de interactividad para la información acerca de CSS diseñando esto:

[image: Sección Hardskills]

**¿Y luego?**

Cuando yo prosigo a clickear sobre el botón 'Read More' ubicado bajo el logo de CSS se abre un container de información acerca frameworks, Sass, y CSS puro.

[image: Interfaz]

**El problema**

La funcionalidad que deseé darle es casi perfecta en su realización, pero hay algo que me molesta y que aún no tengo los conocimientos para editarlo completamente por mi cuenta: *la información comienza a mostrarse únicamente al hacer click sobre algún logo (Bootstrap, Tailwind, etc...)*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Qué estoy buscando?**

Al presionar el 'Read More' que abre el container oculto sucede que no hay ningún tipo de información y me parece poco estético, **busco entender de qué manera puedo dejar por defecto seleccionado el primer ítem: en este caso sería Bootstrap**, es decir, que quede así al presionar el botón 'Read More'.

[image: Deseo]

**Códigos:**

**HTML**

```html
<div class="hardskills-readmore">
    <button class="readmore-btn" id="readmore_btn">Read More</button>
    <div class="hide" id="hideText">
        <ul>
            <li class="li bs"><i class='bx bxl-bootstrap'></i></li>
            <li class="li tw"><i class='bx bxl-tailwind-css' ></i></li>
            <li class="li sass"><i class='bx bxl-sass' ></i></li>
            <li class="li css-pure"><i class='bx bxs-file-css'></i></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="block">
                <h5><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a></h5>
                <p>Like many, <b>Bootstrap</b> was the first framework I used in CSS. Personally I don't like it because it messes up the readability of the HTML code. Beyond my preferences, I usually use it if I need something punctual and fast.</p></div>
            <div class="block">
                <h5><a href="https://tailwindcss.com/">Tailwind CSS</a></h5>
                <p>Unlike Bootstrap, <b>Tailwind</b> seems to me to be a much neater and cleaner framework with respect to code translation. </p>
                <p>In addition to the above highlights, I believe that this project created by Wathan and Schoger offers much more extensive customization.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <h5><a href="https://sass-lang.com/">Sass</a></h5>
                <p>Truly my favorite tool! <b>Sass</b>, just like the name says, is awesome.</p>
                <p>In itself, the fact of being able to work the project in such an organized way thanks to imports and nestings is a real madness.  In addition, being able to add variables, mixins, make extends... SCSS is my best friend when it comes to styles.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <h5>Pure CSS</h5>
                <p>Before learning about and using the above tools I devoted a great deal of attention to understanding the roots of <b>cascading style sheets</b>.</p>
                <p>When it comes to layout I excel in the use of grid, flex and finally box-modeling for small details.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS (SCSS)**

```css
.hardskills-readmore{
@include flex(column, center, center);
margin: 10px 0px;
    button{
        border-radius: 0px;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #000000;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 20px;
        background: #ffffff;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
        border: solid #000000 2px;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
            &:hover{
                transition: .5s;
                background: #8bd9d5;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
            }
            &:hover:active{
                transform: translateY(3px);
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
                color: black;
            }
    }
    .hide{
    display: none;
    @include glassmorphism(shadow);
    margin: 10px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
        ul{
            width: 100%;
            @include flex(row, flex-start, center);
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }
        li{
            @include glassmorphism(shadow);
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 1em;
            margin: 0 2em 0 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all .5 ease;
                i{
                    margin: auto;
                    font-size: 50px;
                }
        }
        li.active{
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        li.bs.active{
            background-color: #5a23c8;;
        }
        li.tw.active{
            background-color: #19B3B8;
        }
        li.sass.active{
            background-color: #D56EA3;
        }
        li.css-pure.active{
            background-color: #009BDE;
        }
        .container{
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 30vh;
            position: relative;
        }
        .block{
            margin: 1em 0em;
            padding: 1em;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all .5 ease;
                h5{
                    font-size: 20px;
                    text-decoration: underline;
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                    a{
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: black;
                    }
                }
                p{
                }
        }
        .block.active{
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    .show{
        transition: all .5 ease;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
const li = document.querySelectorAll('.li')
const block = document.querySelectorAll('.block')

li.forEach((cadaLi, i)=>{
    li[i].addEventListener('click',()=>{

        li.forEach((cadaLi, i)=>{
            li[i].classList.remove('active')
            block[i].classList.remove('active')
        })

        li[i].classList.add('active')
        block[i].classList.add('active')
    })
})
```

Comment: No sé si te funcionará al 100%, pero prueba poner justo antes del `li.forEach` (debajo de `const block` ....) las líneas `li[0].classList.add('active')` y `block[0].classList.add('active')`.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez si lo coloca justo antes del `forEach` añadirá la clase `active` para luego en el `forEach` quitarla, por lo tanto el comportamiento sería el mismo.
Debería ir una vez acaba el bucle.

Comment: Nop, la clase no la quita hasta que no des un click. Nota que el remove lo tienes dentro de un addEventListener. ¿Lo probaste?

Comment: Aunque da igual también si la pones luego del bucle. Es lo mismo. Como te comenté, todo lo que está dentro del addEventListener solo se va a ejecutar única y exclusivamente cuando se haga click. Antes o después da igual, solo inicializa el primer `li` y el primer `block` con la clase active. Alternativamente puedes ponerla directa en el html en los dos elementos que quieras que estén inicializados.

Comment: Para mi, basta con usar [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) sobre el botón que desees dentro del manejador de evento que uss al hacer clic sobre el botón de mostrar más.

Comment: Yo creo que con ponerle la clase `active` en lugar de `block` al primer elemento de la clase container debería valer.

Comment: @Suso efectivo y sencillo! muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue la dictada por @Suso. Con darle la clase 'active' tanto al ícono de BS como a su respectivo div contenedor de texto ha quedado marcado por default.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.